# Bash script to remove large number of users is not running

Tags: linux, bash

my bash script wont run, and does not output anything past `echo "Running gke old user cleanup"`. There is no fail message, it just doesn't run. Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

date
echo "Running old user cleanup"

for user in $(awk -F':' '$1 ~ /^kub-[a-z0-9]{20}$/ { print $1 }' /etc/passwd); do
  echo "Cleaning up '${user}'"
  userdel -r "${user}"
  rc=$?
  if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Failed to cleanup '${user}': exit code: ${rc}"
  else
    echo "Successfully cleaned up '${user}'"
  fi
done
```

Comment: May be, it does run but the loop condition is false? Check if `awk -F':' '$1 ~ /^gke-[a-z0-9]{20}$/ { print $1 }' /etc/passwd` outputs anything at all.

Comment: Add a `set -x` after the shebang to make it verbose, also don't read lines with for see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and  https://shellcheck.net for validating shell scripts.

Comment: @Jetchisel could you show me how to re-write line 9 so it is compliant with the wiki page above. Thanks

Comment: @zarrexx parse the output of `awk` see  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 look for the Process substitution approach.

Comment: `awk -F':' '$1 ~ /^gke-[a-z0-9]{20}$/ { print $1 }' /etc/passwd | while read -r  user; do` will solve the shellcheck problem. But I'm with  `PP` above. Does running the bare command produce any output? Good first Q! Good luck.

Comment: Just to confirm, does the script *exit*? It's clearly *running*, as it produces the first line of output.

Comment: My regex was incorrect, something I have overlooked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe simplify the loop.

```
while read user
do if userdel -r "${user}"
   then echo "Successfully cleaned up '${user}'"
   else echo "Failed to cleanup '${user}': exit code: '$?'"
   fi
done < <( awk -F':' '$1 ~ /^gke-[a-z0-9]{20}$/ { print $1 }' /etc/passwd )
```

Should at least be easier to debug.
Add `set -x` as suggested to see what's being evaluated.